# Using UTL_FILE in ADW

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

Is there anyway I can use UTL_FILE in Autonomous Database to an Object Storage or another Cloud storage? I am asking that because we can't use OS files in ADB.

Here an example of the line but in on-premise env. :

UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_file, 'col1,col2,col3');

Answer (score 0):

Filesystem directories are supported, and documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/create-manage-directory.html#GUID-5EC418F4-2084-4884-8D1E-BACA56F143F9).  Any file you put in the filesystem will count against your storage, just to make sure you are aware.
You can use UTIL_FILE to write to the database file system followed by DBMS_CLOUD.PUT_OBJECT to copy that file a bucket in object store. Use DBMS_CLOUD.DELETE_FILE to delete the file from the database object store if needed.  I do it all the time and it works well.

My guess is the  p_dir  is a parameter to a PL/SQL procedure. If that's the case,  p_dir  should be set to a value equal to a valid database directory object. DATA_PUMP_DIR exists by default in ADW, so it could be something like this:

```
BEGIN
my_file_proc(
p_file => 'my_file.csv',
p_dir => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR');
END;
```

Comment: Why is the second paragraph and the code snippet relevant to the answer? Where is `my_file_proc` declared?